# Creating a Responsive Layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a responsive webpage using bootstrap,but I'm confused on how to start.Can anyone help me to move into the right direction?
Here is my code
https://jsfiddle.net/c30a7bd2/
`It should be responsive for all the devices.`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Use media queries or search for bootstrap, Stack overflow team is to help and guide, not to complete your task or work.

Comment: Pick some bootstrap free layout from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples and start modifying this layout according to your website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the downvotes, here's some info to get you started.

**Process:**

Design from smallest viewport to biggest. i.e. design your responsive site first for mobile devices in portrait, then mobile landscape, then tablet portrait, then tablet landscape, then smallest desktop, then largest desktop. If you look at the Chrome dev tools, you will see an icon on the left-top to the right of the arrow icon. This puts the browser into responsive design mode that lists the most common devices. Very helpful.

**Learn about media queries:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

There is a lot of stupid confusion about how to use @media queries correctly. Let me set you straight right from the beginning.

You only need to worry about min-width. Don't think about ranges, don't use anything else other than min-width.

Here's why.

Since we're writing our css from the **smallest device width** first, as browser widths increase all we're doing is **overriding earlier set styles**. That's it. That literally is the secret to doing great, simple responsive css coding.

**What breakpoints to use:**

Again, lots of clever engineers try to be too clever. They introduce odd breakpoints, try to avoid pixel 'px' definitions, etc. Stop doing that.

Remember, since we're are writing our code mobile portrait first (the smallest device size), there is no media-query for this. Its just css.

Here's the breakpoints you should start with:

```
/* all mobile portrait coding goes first */

@media all and (min-width: 480px) {
  /* this is the most common mobile landscape minimum width */
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* this is the most common minimum tablet width */
}

@media all and (min-width: 1024px) {
  /* this is the most common minimum desktop width. It also is the 
     most common minimum tablet landscape width. */
}

@media all and (min-width: 1300px) {
  /* this is the most common minimum wide desktop width. 
     This is the only media query you might consider setting to 1200px
     if your graphic design requires it. */
}
```

That's it. That is quite literally everything you know to get started writing great responsive css.

Just remember the key concept is utilizing inheritance. 80% of your css should probably be written for the mobile portrait size first. All of those styles get inherited into wider and wider screen widths. Then override them as necessary for the new wider screen. You will find that as your media queries increase, there is less and less css in them.

Have fun and write great code!